# Как вернуть в return разные типы данных?

Tags: java, return

Только начинаю изучать Java. Задача про кварталы года, столкнулся с проблемой:
если вводить не валидные значения, что лучше всего возвращать? Хотел изначально вернуть "invalid data", но там тип int, поэтому решил вернуть просто 0.
Как бы вы решили эту задачу с return
Буду благодарен за советы :)

Код:

```
public static void main (String args[]){

    System.out.println(quarterOf(1));     // First quarter
    System.out.println(quarterOf(4));    // Second quarter
    System.out.println(quarterOf(7));    // Third quarter
    System.out.println(quarterOf(10));     // Fourth quarter
}

public static int quarterOf(int month) {
    if (month >0 && month <=3)
        return 1;
    else if(month >3 && month <=6)
        return 2;
    else if(month >6 && month <=9)
        return 3;
    else if(month >9 && month <=12)
        return 4;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: В случае неправильных входных данных бросайте исключение [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

Comment: можно не писать в одном условии if month <= 3, а сразу в следующем if month > 3, и так ясно, что дальше пройдет только если month больше 3. И так по всем условиям.

Comment: у вас все слишком сложно. это должно быть примерно так:     public static int quarterOf (int month) {
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) throw new RuntimeException("Month " + month + " not exist");
        else return month/3+1;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Это типичная задача и для нее есть много решений в зависимости от того, что именно Вы решаете.

Классическое решение, которое взяли и Вы - сделать некоторое магическое значение, которое будет означать ошибку. А что бы оно не было таким магическим, это можно завернуть в константу (`final`:) ).

Второе хорошее решение - бросать исключение. Хорошая часть этого - ошибку сложно  проигнорировать в отличии от магического значения. Но некоторые люди не любят исключения. Мне этот способ нравится, особенно, если это идет проверка пользовательского ввода, данных много и не хочется запутаться в сотнях if.

Следующий способ - возвращать не просто int (или что Вам нужно), а завернуть его в отдельный класс (или к примеру в [Optional](https://habr.com/ru/post/346782/)). Преимущество такого способа - теперь можно вернуть не просто "ошибка", а ( в случае своего класса) и некоторые детали ошибки. Я видел, как люди в Java делают свой class Int, у которого есть булевый признак "валиден". И потом его везде используют. И при попытке доступа к данным, когда они не установлены, можно просто бросать исключение. Кому исключения не нравятся - можно проверить валидность ручками. Я такой способ часто использую (правда не в java).

Если посмотреть на Go, то там очень похожая система. Только там с функции возвращается две переменные и одна с них результат, а другая признак успешности.

Ну и для особых случаев, когда все сильно запущенно, можно поступить по "ООП" - делаем базовый класс для результата и несколько наследников в зависимости от результата (ошибка - это тоже результат). У этого способа есть один большой минус - при неправильном подходе появляется куча мест, где происходит проверка типа. Вот этого нужно сильно-сильно избегать.